# Associate groups or attributes to a SharePoint user

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, groups, grouping

I need to associate some groups or attributes to a SharePoint user and be able to query for those, maybe by using the `_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx` or `/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx`.

Is this possible in SharePoint 2010? I'm thinking about the User Profile Service Application -> Manage User Properties section. Is  that the place or is there something easier?

I would think a custom list with the user as a first column and a list of groups/attributes as a second column would be a possible workaround but maybe there's something out of the box?

Could I have those groups read from Active Directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, You can add custom properties to a user profile . Check this out : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262327.aspx.

You can also map Active Directory attribute to a user profile property.Check this out : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx